# Index.php not avaialble on my apache server

Tags: apache, web, server

In my server, whenever type as 127.0.0.1 i.e, http://localhost, the browser will takes me to the index.html instead of index.php. why I'm getting like this? how can I route the localhost to index.php?

Answer (score 0):

remove index.html or change the order in httpd.conf like

```
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    DirectoryIndex index.html
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Sir, the httpd.conf file is not available in apache2 right? How can I edit that? I did include a statement 'DirectoryIndex index.php' in .htaccess file. After that my browser redirecting always to index.php when I search for localhost.